# Finding submodules of a specific module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

We consider the ring $R= \left\lbrace \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b&c\\0&d&e\\0&0&f\end{smallmatrix}\right) : \mbox{all entries are in } \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace $.

And let $M$ be the $R$-module of all $3 \times 1$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}$.

I am looking for the submodules of $M$, so I started by looking for the subgroups... But I need some more help !

Besides, is there something to be said about $M$? The way I see it, it's not free... but can we say something else about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the matrices are upper-triangular you have the following submodules:
$$M_0 = 0 \qquad M_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \ast \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad M_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \ast \\ \ast \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad M_3 = M = \begin{bmatrix} \ast \\ \ast \\ \ast \end{bmatrix}$$
Try proving that these are in fact all possible submodules.

Comment: @Carla The "obvious" candidates for subgroups are the triples which are nonzero only one one coordinate. But then when you start examining how they multiply with the triangular matrices, you would quickly notice that they don't remain closed under multiplication by things in $R$. Intuitively, that's why they expand a little bit to be nonzero in more places, and that's how you'd figure out this idea.

Comment: @jim These submodules are not free, right?

Comment: @CarlaB. Correct, you can see this by their $\mathbb R$-dimension.  A free module would have to have dimension some positive multiple of the dimension of the ring.

Comment: @Jim One last thing please... Can these submodules be written as direct summands of free $R$-modules?

Comment: @Jim Actually what would a free $R$-module look like?

Comment: A free left $R$-module is just a direct sum of a bunch of copies of the ring with left multiplication as the action.

Comment: @jim oh... but i wanna show that these submodules are projective which is equivalent to showing that they are direct summands of free $R$-modules.

Comment: @jim are you sure about that? Cause my problem was to prove that $M$ and its submodules are in fact projective $R$-modules :(

Comment: @CarlaB. Can you think of any submodules of R that look like those submodules of M? Do they exactly form a direct sum of R?

Comment: @Jim: This ring is sneaky. M_1 does not embed in M_2 even though it looks like it does. Look at how the action of diag(1,0,0) differs on M_1 and Soc(M_2).  There is a *very* similar ring where your argument does work (you require a=b=f) and then all the simple modules are isomorphic.

Comment: @Jim: Super-sneaky! (I had my modules upside down; row/column issues). Sorry, M3 does not surject onto M2. Check the action of diag(0,0,1).

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Ack, you're right.  I'm used to the commutative world where mult by something is always a hom.

Comment: @CarlaB. So I was totally wrong about them being projective.  To get that they're projective, try showing that as left modules $R$ is isomorphic to $M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus M_3$.

Comment: This means, by the way, that $R$ is **not** indecomposable as I had claimed earlier.

Comment: @jim Can I show that $M_3$ is projective without using what you wrote above; i.e. without using the submodules? In fact, I want to show that it's projective AND injective...